# How to find the maximum number of square groups in a board

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

I'm stuck with the following problem:
Given an n*m board, find the maximum number of square groups that can be positioned on the board.
What are square groups?

- They contain 4 distinct squares named: a, b, c, d
- a should be the neighbor of b
- b should be the neighbor of c
- c should be the neighbor of d
- Two squares are considered neighbors if they are adjacent to each other vertically or horizontally **but not diagonally**.
- Each square can belong to only one square group

I guess the problem should be handled by max flow network algorithms but I don't know how to model it to a graph.
Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: 
The answer is ⌊mn/4⌋, but we need to prove it with Max Flow Network.

Comment: Isn't answer always $\lfloor mn/4\rfloor$?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Thanks for your comment. I edited the problem expectation.

Comment: (Tetris shapes)

Comment: @greybeard Not all the Tetris shapes satisfy the constraints.

Comment: Do you imply *Neither $c$ nor $d$ shall be a neighbour of $a$, nor $d$ of $b$*? Oh, wait, "the T" can't be labelled keeping the constraints.

Comment: There's no connection to network flow...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since each square consists of $4$ cells and an $n \times m$ matrix contains $nm$ cells, you can clearly fit at most $\lfloor nm/4 \rfloor$ many different cells.

If $n,m$ are both even, then you can fit $nm/4$ different square-shaped squares. In all other cases, you have to be more cunning. I won't ruin the joy of the puzzle by explaining how to handle the other cases.